# Twitter Bootstrap top menu unknown component slides down

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm having a problem with the top-bar menu. When I choose an item from the dropdowns, all the events are fired correctly, JavaScript is OK, but there is a visual something (a `div` probably?) that slides down and then disappears. It looks like this:

[image: ugly sliding-down bug image]

I'm not a Twitter Bootstrap expert, but I expect I've got some invalid HTML put there. Entire HTML code is available here: https://github.com/pateketrueke/json-schema-faker/blob/gh-pages/src/index.html, but probably the most important part is this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            [...]
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Samples <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">faker.js</li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="example_faker" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">faker example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">chance.js</li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="example_chance" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">chance example</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">other</li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="example_boolean" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">boolean</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="example_integer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">integer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id="example_array" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">array</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

- Twitter Bootstrap version is v3.3.4 (from bower.json).
- The code of this page is kept here: https://github.com/pateketrueke/json-schema-faker/tree/gh-pages.
- The site is available online at: http://json-schema-faker.js.org/. Try to click "Samples" in the top-bar menu and then choose any option to see this strange thing sliding down and disappearing afterwards...

The question is: what can I do to remove the "sliding-down-and-disappearing-thing" bug?

---

*EDIT*

This app supports the mobile version as well. It looks like this:

[image: mobile version mainpage image]

When you touch the top right hand nav button, the menu appears:

[image: mobile version mainmenu image]

Now when I click samples, the submenu appears:

[image: mobile version samples submenu image]

And when I click any of the options, I would like all menus to hide (collapse), just to see the demo immediately.

Now the mobile works as intended :). And I'd like the non-mobile-sliding-bug solution not ot break the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Remove the 2 css classes.

This 2 classes are supposed to works with the dropdown system. So the dropdown system try to do something weird with this div and it doesn't really works.

Comment: your solution solves the sliding problem, but it completely brakes the mobile version of the page. I use Google Chrome to simulate mobile viewport - see that it crashes with those classes removed.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap menu is not designed to work like this.
Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns and preview it as a mobile device as well.

A simple workaround for what you want to do would be to have JS that will do the hiding, like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="hideNavbarMenu()" id="example_chance">chance example</a>
```

And the JS:

```
function hideNavbarMenu() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
}
```

Note that I also removed the `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` from the links.

Comment: I have extended the question with images of the mobile version. Unfortunately, your solution breaks the mobile: choosing any of sample options *doesn't* hide entire menu in mobile (and it should). Maybe there is a java solution for that...?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Look updated answer. The JS also gets rid of the animation boostrap has (which I personally hate) as it is not using the **"navbar-collapse collapsing"** class as an intermediate.